# Slicing the values of object type in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a DataFrame where all of the values in the column show the *Date of Publication*

[image]

I need to remove an additional text to have the following result:

From:

> 1879 [1879]

To

> 1879

I have checked the datatype and god the following result:

```
Identifier               int64
Edition Statement       object
Place of Publication    object
Date of Publication     object
Publisher               object
Title                   object
Author                  object
Contributors            object
Flickr URL              object
dtype: object
```

Finally, I have tried the following method but it did not work for me.

```
new_books = books['Date of Publication'].astype(object).apply(lambda x: x.str.slice(0, 3))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of wrapping your call inside of `apply` you just operate on the `Series` itself:

```
df["Date of Publication"].astype(str).str.slice(0, 4)
```